# Postfix-Mailman "Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table"

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, ubuntu-14.04, postfix-mta, mailman

I assume the error is an issue with my postfix configuration. I've followed the steps in the instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/mailman.html) to set up apache/postfix/mailman.

*Real domain replaced with mydomain.com*
I've created a default mail list called mailman. When I send an email to mailman@mydomain.com I get the error "Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table" in the mail.log.

```
550 5.1.1 <mailman@mydomain.com>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table; from=<-----@gmail.com> to=<mailman@mydomain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-wi0-f174.google.com>
```

Excerpts from my postfix/main.cf:

```
myhostname = mydomain.com
mydestination = mydomain.com, localhost
inet_protocols = ipv4
relay_domains = mydomain.com
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
mailman_destination_recipient_limit = 1
```

Excerpts from /etc/postfix/transport

```
mydomain.com mailman:
```

Excerpt from postfix/master.cf

```
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}
```

If I understand correctly how it should work...

1. mail comes in to mydomain.com
2. postfix validates the hostname against $myhostname
3. postfix finds mydomain.com under relay_domains
4. postfix relays the mail to the transport listed under transport_maps
5. *failing here?* the postmap table finds that mailman@mydomain.com matches mydomain.com
6. postmap directs the mail to the mailman: transport defined in master.cf
7. the transport mailman: calls postfix-to-mailman.py, and mailman handles the mail

Comment: You are correct! It is recommended not to use postfix-to-mailman.py but use the "alias" method. All the steps are correct except I don't understand why you have to copy /etc/aliases to /var/lib/mailman/data/aliases and you don't need to put mailman/data/alias into alias_database. The official guide to integrate postfix and mailman can be found here, [http://www.list.org/mailman-install/postfix-integration.html](http://www.list.org/mailman-install/postfix-integration.html) Keep in mind that /usr/local/mailman in the link would be /lsr/lib/mailman if you are using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know if this qualifies as an answer but after doing much more reading I came to this conclusion, and hopefully it helps someone else.

There are two ways to configure mailman with postfix.
1. Use the transport maps, as I was trying above
2. Alias mapping

From my reading, method 1 which uses 'postfix-to-mailman.py' is unofficial and not well supported. So I attempted to try method 2 and it worked!

Steps:
**Remove transport method**

Remove lines from postfix/main.cf:

```
relay_domains = mydomain.com
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
mailman_destination_recipient_limit = 1
```

Remove lines from master.cf:

```
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
   flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
   ${nexthop} ${user}
```

Remove any lines from /etc/postfix/transport:

```
lists.domain.com   mailman:
```

**[Switch to alias method](http://www.list.org/mailman-install/postfix-integration.html)**

Uncomment line in /usr/lib/mailman/Mailman/mm_cfg.py

```
MTA = 'Postfix'
```

Copy alias file to mailman directory and run genaliases to create the alias db

```
sudo cp /etc/aliases /var/lib/mailman/data/aliases
sudo /usr/lib/mailman/bin/genaliases
sudo chomod g+w /var/lib/mailman/data/aliases.db
```

Update alias_maps in postfix/main.cf to point to new alias file

```
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases,hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/aliases
```

Reload and restart

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postfix reload
sudo service postfix restart
```

Comment: `s/chomod/chmod/` please :) (one shouldn't add mailman aliases to alias_database as noted below too)

Comment: I have tried your configuration, but when I try to send to a list, I get a 554 error (relay access denied), so I had to change but to using transport maps (with the postfix-to-mailman.py script). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. After much pain, I got mailing list work with the following steps:

1. In /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/mailman.conf, I changed as follows.
   (For apache2 version 2.4 and above)

> ```
> <Directory /var/lib/mailman/archives/public/>
> Options FollowSymlinks
> AllowOverride None
> #    Order allow,deny
> #    Allow from all
> Require all granted
> </Directory>
> ```

2. Even then, with no mail sent to the list, the web page

> http://finelists.kalidoss.com/pipermail/finelists/

complained that I do not have permission to view the page.

3. Next, I went to the 'admin' web interface of 'finelists'

> http://finelists.kalidoss.com/cgi-bin/mailman/admin/finelists

and added the email ids (from whom I may be getting mails) as trusted ones.

4. Thereafter, I sent a check email from `kk@gmail.com` to
   `test@gmail.com` (mails addressed to `test@gmail.com` will be delivered
   to the `finelists`) and it was displayed alright.
5. Please use suitable substitutes for finelists, kalidoss.com, kk@gmail.com,test@gmail.com

Hope this helps someone.